# Why Does This Hold True?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

[image]

I don't understand why this is true. Why does cos^2(x) not affect the convergence?

Comment: In which sense are you defining improper integrals here? Riemann? (This really only matters for the proof.)

Comment: What do we know about $ f $ ?

Comment: Think about the comparison test and the fact that $|\!\cos(x)|\leq1$.

Comment: @YiFan but $ f $ must have values in $ \mathbb{R}_{+} $ so that we could use the comparaison test. That's why I asked him to tell us more informations about $ f \cdot $

Comment: @CHAMSI we know f is continuous  on R and f(x) >= 0  for all x e R

Comment: Then it is possible, as @YiFan said, to use the comparaison test. Observe that : $$ \cos^{2}{\left(x\right)}f\left(x\right)=\underset{\overset{x\to +\infty}{}}{\mathcal{O}}{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)} $$

Comment: @CHAMSI I don't understand how it approaches 0 as x approaches +infinity? Is it not a divergent value?

Comment: The big O notation, $ \mathcal{O}\left(1\right) $ for exemple, doesn't designate a function that approaches $ 0 $, it designates a bounded function. Little o notation, $ \mathcal{o}\left(1\right) $ in particular, designates a function that approaches $ 0 \cdot $

Comment: $0\le |cos^2(x)f(x)|\le |f(x)|$  Therefore dominant convergence applies.

Answer (score 1):

By the comparison test, we know that if $f(x)\ge g(x)\ge0$ then:

1. If $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges then so does $\int_{a}^{\infty}g
   (x)dx$.
2. If $\int_{a}^{\infty}g(x)dx$ diverges then so does $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$.

Consider the first case above.

Suppose $g(x)=\cos^2(x)f(x)$. Since we know that $\cos^2(x) \in [0,1]$ we can conclude that the condition: $f(x)\ge g(x)\ge0$ is met (since $f(x)>0$ and continuous).

The proposition in the OP then follows that if $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges, then so too must $\int_{1}^{\infty}\cos^2(x)f(x)dx$.